# Computer Game/Software that Makes Memorizing Fun

Tags: game, educational

I am trying to memorize word for word several chapters from a book. LOTS OF TEXT. Every memorization program online uses flash cards or hides every other word. This gets boring really fast, though. Does a game exist for helping someone memorize? It would be neat if there was a game out there that required you to memorize something to power up your spaceship or something along those lines...

Comment: I don't think a lot of people would agree with your idea of fun and neat.  This sounds very, very niche.  I would doubt very much that such a product exists for what you want.